# Check if message will be sent using iMessage or cellular network

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Using `MFMessageComposeViewController` to check if the device `canSendText` or not. All is Ok but is there anyway to detect that message will be sent using iMessage or Cellular SMS. There's a persistent requirement that user should be alerted if the text is being sent via iMessage and internet is not connected? I am just wondering if there could be a proper solution for this?

Thanks for you time

Answer (score 4):

There is not way for you to know wether the message is sent via iMessages or as a SMS.
Apple does not provide any API methods to detect this.

Also the messages app will not use iMessage is there is not internet connect, if the internet connection is down it will send a normal SMS.

If you are sending a a message to an email adres via iMessage then the send button is disabled if no internet connection is available.